# Basis for kernel of trace map

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, trace-map

Let $T: M_{n \times n}(F) \rightarrow F$  be defined by $T(A) = tr(A)$.

I want to find out what a basis is for the kernel $N(T)$ of this linear map. I know $tr(A) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} A_{ii}$.

I also know the dimension of the kernel has to be $n^2 - 1$, because $rank(T) = 1$ and $dim(M_{n \times n} (F)) = n^2$. But how do I find a suitable basis for the kernel?

Comment: Take the standard basis of $M_{n,n}(F)$. All these elements belong to $N(T)$ expect $n$ of them. Then you should be able to figure out how to make $n-1$ independent elements of $N(T)$ among these. If not, try with $n=2$ and $n=3$ to see how things work.

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf: You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\delta_{ij}$ be the matrix with a $1$ in $(i,j)$ and $0$s elsewhere. Then if $i \neq j$, this matrix has zeroes on the entire diagonal; so $\text{Tr}(\delta_{ij}) = 0$. We now have $n^2-n$ linearly independent terms; we just need to find $n-1$ more.

So far we've ignored the diagonal, so let's find elements of the kernel of $\text{Tr}$ that *only* have elements on the diagonal. One set is $\delta_{11} - \delta_{ii}$ for $n \geq i > 1$; you should check that, indeed, $$\{\delta_{ij} : 1 \leq i \neq j \leq n \} \cup \{\delta_{11}-\delta_{ii} : 1 < i \leq n \}$$ is a linearly independent set. Then you're automatically done, as you know that $N(\text{Tr})$ has dimesnion at least $n^2-1$; but it can't have dimension $n^2$, as $\text{Tr}(\delta_{11}) = 1 \neq 0$. So this is a basis for $N(\text{Tr})$.

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, but I don't understand the part where you say "we just need to find n-1 more". Why is that?

Comment: @Kamil We want to find $n^2-1$ linearly independent elements of the kernel; we have $n^2-n$; and $(n^2-n)+(n-1) = n^2-1$.

Comment: I see, thanks. What are the matrices in the set $(\delta_{11} - \delta_{ii}: 1 < i \leq)$? Don't we need to add the elements on the diagonal?

Comment: @Kamil Those are matrices with only elements in the diagonal: they have a $1$ at $(1,1)$, a $-1$ at $(i,i)$, and a $0$ everywhere else. These have 0s everywhere but the diagonal, but trace zero because $1-1=0$.

Comment: Thanks very much for the answers! That helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Let $E_{ij}$ denote the matrix whose entries are all zero except for the $i,j$ entry, which is a $1$.  Clearly, these matrices form a basis of $M_{n\times n}(F)$.

Consider the matrices $E_{ij}$ with $i \neq j$ and $(E_{ii} - E_{nn})$ with $i<n$.